# Different footer on page 1 and rest

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have got a document that uses the same footer for all pages but I want to change the layout and have different footer on the first page and all the rest of the pages.
Sadly I have no clue how to change the footer. I think I have to use two different footer but where do I address the correct page?

```
Public Sub footer()
Set p_image = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:= _
    p_path & "BwK_" & INIT.p_CO & "_XX_XX_FL_2020.jpg", _
    LinkToFile:=True, _
    SaveWithDocument:=False, _
    Width:=MillimetersToPoints(170), _
    Height:=MillimetersToPoints(20), _
    Anchor:=ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range)
With p_image
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
    .Left = MillimetersToPoints(20)
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
    .Top = MillimetersToPoints(275)
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help and extensive documentation on your page, it helped me finding the correct answer:

```
Public Sub footer2()
    Set p_image = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:= _
        p_path & "BwK_" & INIT.p_CO & "_XX_XX_FL_2022_Primary.png", _
        LinkToFile:=True, _
        SaveWithDocument:=False, _
        Width:=MillimetersToPoints(170), _
        Height:=MillimetersToPoints(20), _
        Anchor:=ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range)
    With p_image
        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
        .Left = MillimetersToPoints(20)
        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
        .Top = MillimetersToPoints(275)
    End With
End Sub
```

In fact the document only uses one section and so I only had to change `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage` to `wdHeaderFooterPrimary`.

Answer (score 1):

The following will set all sections in a document to have a different first page for headers AND footers.

```
Sub HeaderFirstPageOn()
    ' Charles Kenyon 2021-12-29
    ' Set Different First Page for Headers and Footers in all sections
    Dim iSections As Long
    Dim iCount As Long
    Let iSections = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    For iCount = 1 To iSections
        Let ActiveDocument.Sections(iCount).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    Next iCount
End Sub
```

Here is a macro that sets this for the first section only.

```
Sub HeaderFirstPageOn1()
    ' Charles Kenyon 2021-12-29
    ' Set Different First Page for Headers and Footers in first section only
        Let ActiveDocument.Sections(1).PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
End Sub
```

Here is a [link to my writing on header and footer settings](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings). Note that this is a Section setting, not a page or document setting and that it applies to both headers and footers. So, if you have footer content, you may need to duplicate it for the first-page header.